# Azure Functions proxy, can't get it to work right

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have two functions, one `Set` and one `Go`, the set takes an href as query string and returns a code (URL shortner). The Go function takes the code and returns the URL. So far i have this :

```
Http Functions:

Api: [GET,POST,HEAD,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS,PATCH,TRACE] http://localhost:7071/api/{*path}
RedirectUrl: [GET] http://localhost:7071/{*shortUrl}
Go: [GET,POST] http://localhost:7071/api/Go/{shortUrl}
Set: [GET,POST] http://localhost:7071/api/Set
```

with following proxies.json :

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/proxies",
  "proxies": {
    "RedirectUrl": {
      "matchCondition": {
        "route": "/{*shortUrl}",
        "methods": [
          "GET"
        ]
      },
      "backendUri": "https://%WEBSITE_HOSTNAME%/api/Go/{shortUrl}"
    },
    "Api": {
      "matchCondition": {
        "route": "/api/{*path}"
      },
      "backendUri": "https://%WEBSITE_HOSTNAME%/api/{path}"
    }
  }
}
```

but there are few missing things which i want to solve :

I would like to be able to do :

1. `http://localhost:7071/api/Go/{shortUrl}` but this gives an exception :

`Executed 'Go' (Failed, Id=f2786621-3486-432b-84c2-1a125b01d1d2) [11-07-2019 10:58:14] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Go. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Exception binding parameter 'shortUrl'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Binding data does not contain expected value 'shortUrl'.`

and i don't know why.

2. I would like to write https://mysite.azurewebsites.net and then redirect to my own website (externally, just an url). If i write https://mysite.azurewebsites.net/WRONGCODE i redirect in the code to external URL but here i don't get to my code so i need to redirect from root in the proxies.json if possible.

How can i achieve this ?

btw. all of this is just a copy of https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/azure-storage-for-serverless-net-apps-in-minutes/?utm_source=jeliknes&utm_medium=github&utm_campaign=storage&WT.mc_id=storage-github-jeliknes

/donnib